# cordova and ionic: how open default map

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

In ionic i have a button and when a user click on that button i want open the apple maps to show the location of a place.

In my controller i have the following code:

```
$scope.openMap = function(){
  if($ionicPlatform.is('ios')){   
    var url="http://maps.apple.com/?address=My+Street+Example"
    window.open(url, '_system'); 
  }
}
```

The problem is that i need to click two times in order to open the apple maps.
The first time i click on the button, the code is executed but never happens (and xcode doesn't show me nothing)

The second time the apple map opens and in the xcode debugger i see the following message:

```
 CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
 Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
 Resetting plugins due to page load.
 Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted
```

What's the problem? Why i need to click two times in order to open the apple maps?